# Почему ifile.read() читает больше байтов, чем я ему сказал?

Tags: c++

Я пытаюсь прочитать первые три байта из файла, однако по факту функция считывает все 8.

```
std::ifstream ifile(filename, std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);
...
char hdr[3];
ifile.read(hdr, 3);
```

Причем она умудряется засунуть эти 8 байтов в массив на 3 ячейки.
Почему так происходит?

Comment: Откуда вы взяли про «все 8»?

Comment: я вывожу hdr в cout и там оказывается 8 символов

Comment: Как выводите? .

Comment: std::cout<<...;

Comment: И оно будет выводить, пока не встретит нулевой байт. В вашем `hdr[3]` есть нулевой байт? Что-то я сомневаюсь

Comment: То есть она продолжает выводить весь мусор, который лежит на стеке после моего массива. Спасибо, совсем забыл что сишные строки надо закрывать нулями

Comment: Умилило это *умудряется засунуть эти 8 байтов в массив на 3 ячейки*...

Answer (score 0):

[`ifstream::read`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) не читает больше, чем указано во втором аргументе, как могло бы показаться.

Наиболее вероятная проблема в том, что вывод содержимого `char*` основан на наличии нулевого терминирующего символа `\0` в цепочке памяти. Именно поэтому, когда используют сырые символьные массивы для хранения null-terminated строк, то один элемент должен быть зарезервирован для хранения этого завершающего нуля.

Самое просто, что можно сделать - это увеличить размер массива на единицу и инициализировать его нулями.

```
char hdr[4] = {};
ifile.read(hdr, 3);
```

После этого можно снова проверить что же считалось из файла в массив.